# flask, gunicorn (gevent), sqlalchemy (postgresql): too many connections

Tags: postgresql, python, gunicorn, heroku, flask

I created `Flask` WSGI-application which uses `gunicorn` as WSGI-server, for DB it uses `PostgreSQL` through `Flask SQLAlchemy` extension. That's all hosted on `Heroku`.

**gunicorn configuration**

- number of workers: 2;
- number of workers connections: 1024;
- number of threads: 1;
- worker class: gevent.

**Heroku PostgreSQL configuration**

- maximum number of connections: 20.

For everything else default configuration is used.

I'm getting this error: `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL: too many connections for role <id>`. Obviously, i'm exceeded allowed number of DB connections.

I tried these things to fix it:

- for SQLAlchemy set `poolclass` to `NullPool`;
- for SQLAlchmey set `pool_recycle` to 2. Number of connections still the same even after more than 2 seconds;
- `session.close()` with `engine.dispose()`;
- number of workers - 2, number of worker connections - 9;
- number of workers - 1, number of worker connections - 18;
- number of workers - 1, number of worker connections - 10, SQLAlchemy `max_overflow = 0`, SQLALchmey `pool_size = 10` (i'm getting this error: `sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 10 overflow 0 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30`).

Nothing of this works. I'm still getting this error even with minimum gunicorn configuration (1 worker with 18 connections). I'm really started not to understand what is really going on.

I thought it worked like this: each worker have it's own instance of engine, and each engine have it's own pool size. So, if there is 2 workers with engine default config (pool size is 5), then we have 2 * 5 = 10 maximum connections to DB. But it looks like this is really not like this.

**Questions**

- How to fix this error?
- How `SQLAlchemy` pooling works with `gevent` workers? i.e., how can i count maximum number of DB connections?
- How should I configure it correctly so that it works as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You mention:

- `worker connections = 1024`
- `threads = 1`

but with `gevent`, the number of worker connections is the total number of (asynchronous) threads running at once.

As a result, you're trying to establish `workers * worker_connections` number of connections, which is definitely higher than you can sustain, based on `pool_size` and `postgres` limits defined.

Start at Postgres and work backwards:

- Postgres = 20 connections max
- instances = 1 (it seems like)?
- `gunicorn` processes = 2
- `worker_connections` = 10 = (20 / 2)
- `pool_size + max_overflow` = 10 [same as `worker_connections`!]
- `pool_size = 10, max_overflow=0` or any combo you want

  - overflow connections get cleaned up asap; pool_size connections can stick around

`worker_connections` and `pool_size+max_overflow` are shared across threads, but not processes.

Note, as soon as you add another instance or anything that talks to the DB, it will use 1 (or more) of those precious 20 Postgres connections, so you'll need to adjust accordingly.